# Finding List index differences with special number setting

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a Python List like this:

```
a = [70,66,63,-1,-1,68,-1,70]
```

By the following code I can get the list of index differences among non-minus-one elements(Since -1 will not appear at the end of the list):

```
res = [idx for idx, val in enumerate(a) if val != -1]
index_diff = [x - res[i - 1] for i, x in enumerate(res)][1:]
```

and index_diff looks like this:

```
[1, 1, 3, 2]
```

Now I would like to make some adjustments, because there is two -1 between 63 and 68, and one -1 between 68 and 70, I would like to deduct the number of -1 between them, so the target should look like this:

```
[1,1,1,1]
```

Anyone can help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [70,66,63,-1,-1,68,-1,70]
res = [idx for idx, val in enumerate(a) if val != -1]
index_diff = [x - res[i - 1] for i, x in enumerate(res)][1:]
```

Keep track of the indexes we've already traversed and then do the subtraction.

```
sumx = 0
new_count = []
for x in index_diff:
    if x == 1:
        sumx +=1
        new_count.append(x)
    else:
        new_count.append(x - len(a[sumx+1:sumx+x]))
        
print(new_count)
```

> [1, 1, 1, 1]